# UnitSimplify rules?

Tags: units

Code as following:

```
In[1]:= constants = Quantity /@ {"PlanckConstant", "BoltzmannConstant", "MolarGasConstant"};
  Print[UnitSimplify[
  UnitConvert[Quantity["AvogadroNumber"]*constants[[2]]]] // N];
  UnitSimplify /@ UnitConvert /@ constants // N

8.31446J/K

Out[3]= {Quantity[6.62607*10^-34, "Joules" "Seconds"], Quantity[1.38065*10^-23, ("Joules")/("Kelvins")], Quantity[8.31446, ("Kilograms" ("Meters")^2)/("Kelvins" "Moles" ("Seconds")^2)]}
```

It seems that the unit of the *molar gas constant* cannot be simplified well enough, and very likely it was because of the `"Moles"` in the unit, for if I calculate the *molar gas constant* by multiplying the *Boltzmann constant* with *Avogadro's number* instead the unit can be simplified well. There is no `"Moles"` in the unit of the latter.

Is there a way to improve the automatic simplification of units in such cases? TKX.

Comment: Before anything else: is the result of `Composition[QuantityUnit, UnitConvert, Quantity] /@ {"PlanckConstant", "BoltzmannConstant", "MolarGasConstant", "AvogadroNumber"}`what you expected it to be?

Comment: Sorry. I expect it to give ```("Joules")/("Kelvins"'Moles")``` as the unit of ```"MolarGasConstant"``` after ```UnitSimplify```. Before unit simplification, the results are fine.

Comment: Evaluating `{UnitSimplify[UnitConvert[Quantity["MolarGasConstant"]]], UnitSimplify[UnitConvert[Quantity["AvogadroConstant"] Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"]]]}` in 11.2 give me results that I expect. How about you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping to try. I am using 12.0.0 and the energy part was not simplified to Joul, using your code.
Yes, it happened to me that some things worked very well in 11.x turned kind of lousy in 12.0. For example, the bounding box of a polar plot could become too small to show all the tick labels. I posted that problem before.